# How does Comcast Xfinity Wi-Fi insert HTML into a web page request?

Tags: wireless-networking, html

How does Comcast’s Xfinity Wi-Fi insert an in-page popup when you login from a computer that you’ve logged in with before?

This most commonly happens when the Wi-Fi connection resets. It shows up within the current web page, then goes away after a few seconds. The page doesn’t show any Comcast hostnames. I did notice this CSS file, that went away after reloading the page. It doesn’t show on HTTPS urls, as expected.

```
http://d5k1a84rm5hwo.cloudfront.net/all-201407312053.css
```

FYI Xfinity Wi-Fi is the Wi-Fi network that is created and managed by Comcast owned equipment and allows you to connect to a hotspot when you’re away from home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technique is known as setting up a [“Captive Portal”](https://personaltelco.net/wiki/CaptivePortal).  The concept as described on that site is simple:

> Captive portals allow you to leverage a common browser as a secure
>   authentication device. They also have the potential to allow you to do
>   everything securely via SSL and IPSec and setup per user quality of
>   service rules, and still maintain an open network.

As far as implementation goes, depends on the network management product being used. It is typically handled by a firewall appliance. For example, [this site](http://wiki.untangle.com/index.php/Captive_Portal) has instructions on how to use Captive Portal settings on [NG Firewall](http://wiki.untangle.com/index.php/Captive_Portal):

> Captive Portal allows administrators to require network users to log
>   in or accept a network usage policy before accessing the internet.
>   Captive Portal can authenticate users against Untangle's built-in
>   Local Directory, Active Directory (if Directory Connector is
>   installed), or RADIUS. It can be used to set up policies (for Policy
>   Manager) by username (or group name if using Active Directory) rather
>   than IP. While Captive Portal is running, captured machines will be
>   forced to authenticate (or just press OK) on the Captive Portal page
>   before they are able to access the internet.

Ditto with the documentation for [pfSense](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Captive_Portal):

> The Captive Portal function in pfSense allows you to secure a network
>   by requiring a username and password (or just a click through),
>   entered on a portal page.